# Cannot create a react project

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to create a React project using npm but I'm failing because the global version of npm-create-react is no longer supported but even I follow what is told me to do it doesn't work anyway.
When I try to use the command

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

I get this error from the console

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/nick/Documents/NFT
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-react-app "my-app"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/nick/.npm/_logs/2022-02-26T08_47_03_397Z-debug.log
```

After I receive this error I type the command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

And in the terminal it gets printed the following message:

```
up to date, audited 1 package in 110ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

After this nothing changes, I still get the same error.
How can I remove this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Follow the documentation and ensure your system meets the minimum requirements, run `npx create-react-app my-app`. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started#quick-start

Comment: I did it but nothing changes

Comment: Nothing changes? You get the same same error as if you had installed globally? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

try running the create react app from npx like this

`npx create-react-app app-name`

Comment: same happens. I'm trying to uninstall node. I'll keep you informed

Comment: I've tried to uninstall completely node but the error keeps happening

Comment: what is your node version?

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using this command

```
npm install -g create-react-app@5.0.0
```

Then I could use again

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

Comment: Accept this answer if this worked.

Comment: I can't yet, I have to wait 2 days

Comment: In my opinion, use `yarn` instead of `npm`. have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to have Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine. To create a project, run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

[Link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) for doc